# Tic Tac Toe game beginner level

Tags: java, arrays, loops, tic-tac-toe

i am new to programming and i was doing a tic tac toe game on beginner level but i can't manage to get my code to repeat when user puts invalid value. Instead of re-asking the question it ends the programme. Can someone help me ? :))

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Subject {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        char[][] GameBoard = new char[3][3];

        for (int row = 0; row < GameBoard.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < GameBoard[row].length; col++) {
                GameBoard[row][col] = (char)('0' + row * 3 + col);
                System.out.print(GameBoard[row][col] + "|" + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
            for (int i = 0; i < GameBoard[row].length * 3; i++) {
                System.out.print("-");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        boolean GameOver = false;

        while (!GameOver) {

            System.out.println("Please enter 'X' or 'O' to choose your character: ");
            char playerSymbol = myScanner.next().charAt(0);
            if (playerSymbol != 'X' && playerSymbol != 'O') {
                System.out.println("Invalid input");
                break;
            }

            System.out.println(" Please enter a number from 0 to 8 to place your character ");
            int NumbersOnBoard = myScanner.nextInt();

            switch (NumbersOnBoard) {
                case 0:
                    GameBoard[0][0] = playerSymbol;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    GameBoard[0][1] = playerSymbol;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    GameBoard[0][2] = playerSymbol;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    GameBoard[1][0] = playerSymbol;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    GameBoard[1][1] = playerSymbol;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    GameBoard[1][2] = playerSymbol;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    GameBoard[2][0] = playerSymbol;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    GameBoard[2][1] = playerSymbol;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    GameBoard[2][2] = playerSymbol;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println(":(");
                    return;
            }

            for (int row = 0; row < GameBoard.length; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < GameBoard[row].length; col++) {
                    System.out.print(GameBoard[row][col] + "|" + "\t");
                }
                System.out.println();
                for (int i = 0; i < GameBoard[row].length * 3; i++) {
                    System.out.print("-");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Most of the things that i tried caused problem with the switch part

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger

Comment: By the way, a little math can be used to eliminate the `switch`, and calculate the row and column directly from `numbersOnBoard`.

Comment: Off-topic:  [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions)

Answer (score 1):

You're telling the code to *exit the loop* when the input is invalid:

```
if (playerSymbol != 'X' && playerSymbol != 'O') {
    System.out.println("Invalid input");
    break;
}
```

If you want to skip the rest of the loop body and re-iterate the loop, the keyword you're looking for is `continue`:

```
if (playerSymbol != 'X' && playerSymbol != 'O') {
    System.out.println("Invalid input");
    continue;
}
```

Comment: Oh...Thanks for the help but i have another question. What about the switch part, code keeps returning to the first question but when i make it so the second part returns invalid what do i need to do if i want it to just restart from there

Comment: @Gkdnzx707: If there's another separate issue that you'd like to ask about, that should be done in another separate Stack Overflow question.  Though, before posting it, this is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  Doing this may help you discover the problem, or at least a more specific question to ask.